# Java - What's the most efficient way of drawing large number of pixels on the screen

Tags: java

I've started working on a program in which I want to completely manipulate how pixels are being drawn to the screen. So I thought of storing the pixels data in an int or byte array and draw each pixel on the screen like every 1 millisecond, but from past experiences I know that this is extremely inefficient and the fps for a 600x550 canvas drops below 5...
So, how come this does not happen when it comes to drawing an image with the same number of pixels? How does this Graphics method work? And are there even more efficient ways of doing it?

Comment: Have a look at [BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html). You can set individual pixels in the image and then draw the image all in one shot.

Comment: `Graphics` is class, for how it works and which methods you have available feel free to follow official [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) 
And about my xp which I am having for this purpose is probably the best Buffered image, as mentioned above, check `setRGB` methods

Comment: Well it would be most efficient to use OpenGL

Comment: Yeah but isn't OpenGL another bunch of code written by somebody? It's not magic, every coder is limited by the programming language, and if one can make something efficient why can't that be a case for somebody else?

Comment: I don't like using other people's API's since they contain things I may not need or I don't understand, I want to have a complete control over my program so I can solve bugs more easily.... Also, BufferedImage is another code made by somebody else, containing so many stuff I don't need, so my question should've probably been "How does BufferedImage" work, but nvm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of showing an image in memory to the screen-buffer is done deep inside the Java API by a process called [blitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_blit). The details differ between the type of image you use and even between Java versions. Images in Java can be 'accelerated' which means they can be anything between an image compatible with your hardware and an image actually residing the GPU's memory. If you instantiate a `BufferedImage`, in my experience it's never 'accelerated' but still very fast.

If you want to write pixels into an array and show them quickly, use the following method:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
image.setAccelerationPriority(0); // Just to be sure
int[] array = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

then just paint the image as usual after manipulating the array.

This has more performance than using `.setRGB()` since no color space conversion is done.

Comment: Okay, I am setting the pixels with `image.getRaster().setPixels()` but the performance is still poor....

Comment: `setPixels` is still very inefficient. I can't verify if it converts colorspace or not but it performs at least three internal method calls per pixel. You really need to get the `int[] array` out of the image and only write to that.